# error message in adding sqlite3 library in my project

Tags: c++, linux, sqlite, cmake

I have a C++ project and i want to use sqlite3 on it. i am using CMake to build and add some line to CMakeLists.txt,here it is:

```
project(Test)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
aux_source_directory(. SRC_LIST)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_LIST})
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG  "-g")

find_path(SQLITE3_INCLUDE_DIR sqlite3.h)
find_library(SQLITE3_LIBRARY sqlite3)
if(NOT SQLITE3_INCLUDE_DIR)
  message(SEND_ERROR "Failed to find sqlite3")
endif()
if(NOT SQLITE3_LIBRARY)
  message(SEND_ERROR "Failed to find the sqlite3 library")
endif()
```

when i want to rum cmake command, it get me`Failed to find sqlite3` and `Failed to find the sqlite3 library` and could find it.

i am using ubuntu+qtcreator and version of sqlite3 that i have installed:

```
> sqlite3 --version
3.8.2 2013-12-06 14:53:30 27392018af4c38cc203a04b8013e2afdb1cebd0d
```

thanks to all...!

Comment: SQLite is embeddable. Why you can't include the source code in?

Comment: Do you have `libsqlite3-dev` installed?

Comment: @Igor i include sqlite3.h in my source! is not enough? or anything else must be included??

Comment: @Mehdi, yes, you need sqlite3.c file as well.

Comment: @Igor Why? Ubuntu already has all the necessary packages. There's hardly any reason to build the sqlite library yourself...

Comment: @DanMašek  not installed, and now installed

Comment: @DanMašek, you are not building the library, you are embedding the latest code of the SQLite, which is less buggy and ultimately remove the necessary dependency. The last point is especially important in a cross-platform environment.

Comment: @Igor  both of them (sqlite3.h and sqlite3.c) is in my project dir(subdir)

Comment: @Dan Mašek when i installed libsqlite3-dev my problem solved...but in my project i am using function sqlite3_open and sqlite3_close and now it get me this error:  undefined reference to `sqlite3_open'

Comment: @mehdi You also need to link your code with the libsqlite3 library. `target_link_library(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SQLITE3_LIBRARY})`

Comment: @Dan Mašek ok thanks lot, my problem solved..very thanks of you!

Answer (score 0):

Hers a mostly working example in ie I've removed irrelevant stuff cmake...

```
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/sqlite3/)
set(sqlite3_srcs 
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/sqlite3/sqlite3.c
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/sqlite3/sqlite3.h 
)
....
add_library(mylib SHARED
  ${sqlite3_srcs} 
)
target_link_libraries(foooo  mylib)
```